# When should I feed my black hole?

Tags: rebuild-the-universe

In the Black Hole tab, I get the option to Feed it.  When I click on it, I get this confirmation:

[image: Black Hole Feeding]

I'm worried by the words "Reset your game".  What exactly is reset?  Do I lose all the units I've made?  What about achievements, unit bonuses, and specials?

Comment: I don't know this game (but I already love it) but from my knowledge from the kittens game, it seems like your game is totally reset, but your overall atoms per second (APS) will be increased by 4% (right now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lose your units, upgrades, bonuses, as well as achievements, but you gain a bonus to your APS.

It's basically a paragon system, where you reset and lose everything, but gain increased APS to get back to where you were faster.

Comment: How is the multiplier determined?  Is it like Clicker Heroes where I can squeeze a few extra APS before resetting?

Comment: The multiplier is actually determined by the amount of atoms you have available to spend, not APS. You can see it by clicking feed when you have a lot of atoms, then spending it all on units and upgrades and clicking feed again, if the difference in atoms is big enough, the multiplier should change. The formula for calculating multiplier is in [this script](http://rebuildtheuniverse.com/Calculs2.js) under the function `calcPres()`

Comment: Looking at that function, it's based on the number of digits of your total atoms.  So once you pass 100 septendecillion there's no change in the black hole bonus until you reach 1 octodecillion, and then nothing again until 10 octodecillion.